# How to add Id_card_number input field in django admin page whenever I add new user in admin?

Tags: python, html, django

I have a problem which I am searching for so many days but not finding an answer. I want new field to be appeared by the name of `Id_card_number` whenever I click `add user` in django admin page. Remember that `Id_card_number` is appearing in registration page but it not appearing in django admin page. Please help.

*forms.py*

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    Id_card_number = forms.CharField(max_length=15, required=True)

    class Meta:
    model = User
    fields  = ['username','email','password1','password2','Id_card_number']
```

*register.html*

```
<form method="POST">
  {%csrf_token%}
<fieldset class="form-group">
  <legend class="border-bottom mb-4" style="font-size: 50px">Join Today</legend><br>
  {{form|crispy}}<br>
</fieldset>
<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to add `Id_card_number` column in User Model by extending django's default User Model.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    Id_card_number = forms.CharField(max_length=15, required=True)
```

**settings.py**

add this:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your-app-name.User'
```

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import *
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

**views.py**

add this:

```
User = get_user_model()
```

then apply `makemigrations` and `migrate`. This will add **Id_card_number** column in your User model.